# Did I play this correctly? $1-2 NL Holdem

Tags: nlhe, cash-game

I'm in the Big Blind with about $180. I get 44's. 5 limpers.

I raise to $13, 2 callers (UTG+3 & the Button).

Flop comes [A,K,4]

I raise $25. Both call.

Turn is a K.

I raise $35. Both call again, but button looks a little disgusted.

So in this position, I'm thinking that the button has an Ace and the quick call by the other player tells me he has a King. On the river, i'm planning on shoving until....

Another King drops on the river, At this point I'm S.O.L in my mind... I check.

UTG+3 bets out $55. The button calls and I fold.

UTG+3 shows K8 for quads, Button Shows an Ace..

Did I play this correctly? Should I have done anything different?

Comment: OMG that is a cooler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Flop** If its rainbow, Thats a decent sized bet.  I guess you could argue for $28-30 being out of position, but your sizing helps your opponents make more mistakes calling with bad aces and kings.

**Turn**  I like this small bet size cause it keeps aces in. AND, on a river brick, you can continue your 'ace' line betting tiny to instigate a reraise from trips as well as get some bad calls from an ace.

**River** Obviously had to fold.

Answer (score 4):

Check OOP with the small PP pre. Raising gets you in lots of spots where you're cbetting with no equity OOP vs multiple opponents or c/f'ing when you miss, which sucks.

As played the Flop bet is good, but the turn bet is way too small. The pot is ~$114 so you should be betting somewhere near $80 (possibly more because $1/$2 players hate folding).

River is standard.

Comment: I understand your thinking, but I didn't want to let either of the fish go on this hand. I knew one had a king and another had an ace. If the river was anything else but a King or an ace. I was shoving on the river and would atleast get one caller. An 80$ bet on the turn commits me to the pot and the king DEF would have sucked out.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand yours. If you really knew one had a King on the turn you should be shoving because $1/$2 players find it really difficult to fold trips, especially fish. It would be a slight overbet but not that much, around $142 or so into about $114.

The king would have sucked out on this particular river, but you're ahead on a vast majority of rivers and want to get in more money sooner.

Comment: By waiting to shove on the river. 1) I don't lose the hook on the Ace. 2) on the occasional suck out, I don't get stacked.

Comment: Shove the turn, not river. This would be an abysmal river to shove.

Comment: You have to maximize your profit against your opponent's whole range.  Keeping aces in for more money, while presumably still stacking kings on the river is the most profitable strategy.